# Creating Insertion Sort in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to create an insertion sort. I am running into a NoMethodError and I was looking for a little help.

```
def insertion_sort array
  (1..array.length-1).each do |pull_position|
    checked_value = array.delete(pull_position)
    insert_point = pull_position

    while checked_value < array[insert_point - 1] and insert_point >= 0 do
      insert_point -= 1
    end

    array.insert(insert_point,checked_value)
  end
end


puts insertion_sort(["goof","fire","apple","charlie","banana","elephant","dog"])
```

Comment: When asking about an exception that was raised, it is always helpful to show precisely what the exception was (cut and paste) and where it occurred.  I suggest you edit to add that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `pull_position` is not an element of `array`. (It's an index.) So `array.delete(pull_position)` returns `nil`, which is assigned to  `checked_value`. `checked_value < array`... raises the exception, because `nil` does not have a method `<`.

Instead of `array.delete(pull_position)` I expect you want `array.delete_at(pull_position)`, though that's not enough to fix the code.

The problem was easy to spot when I ran the code and got this exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):39:in `block in insertion_sort'
        ...
```

This is valuable information.  It tells me the exception occurred when

```
while checked_value < array[insert_point - 1] and insert_point >= 0 do
```

was executed and that `checked_value` was equal to `nil`.  So it was then just a matter of seeing where `checked_value` was last assigned a value (`nil`), and bingo!